# ¿Cómo obtener el promedio de un conjunto de datos agrupado por una o mas variables?

Tags: python, group-by

Hola estoy usando el siguiente dataframe, y necesito calcular lo siguiente por ejemplo donde esta el 0 en "alt", la media de todos los valores de de "ktemp" que coincidan con 2007002 y luego todos los valores de "ktemp" que coincidan con 2007005 y asi sucesivamente.

```
   alt ev   orbit   date    ktemp
    0   0   27447   2007002 101.2
        1   27447   2007002 130.3
        2   27491   2007005 115.2
        3   27491   2007005 120.2
        4   27491   2007005 105.3
        5   27506   2007006 104.5
        6   27506   2007006 106.7
        7   27506   2007006 135.2
        8   27550   2007009 115.3
        9   27550   2007009 102.5
       10   27550   2007009 104.2
       11   27550   2007009 102.1
       12   27594   2007012 100.3
       13   27594   2007012 99.2
       14   27594   2007012 98.3
   1    0   27447   2007002 100.2
        1   27447   2007002 97.4
        2   27491   2007005 95.3
        3   27491   2007005 99.6
        4   27491   2007005 98.2
        5   27506   2007006 97.3
        6   27506   2007006 98.1
        7   27506   2007006 97.2
        8   27550   2007009 99.8
        9   27550   2007009 90.2
        10  27550   2007009 90.5
        11  27550   2007009 91.4
        12  27594   2007012 95.2
        13  27594   2007012 94.3
        14  27594   2007012 93.5
```

Comment: ¿ ktemp es siempre NaN ?

Comment: voy a editar mi pregunta

Comment: @marmurar ya lo edite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas es agrupar por un conjunto de datos y calcular su media, en este caso por cada tipo de dato de la columna date y cada dato de la columna alt. Lo haré en partes, primero agrupas y así compruebas que es lo que buscas:

```
df.groupby(['alt','date'])
```

Luego Filtro la columna por la cual deseo calcula media calcula la media:

```
df.groupby(['alt','date'])['ktemp'].mean()
```

No es la única opción obviament, y **nota:** 'ktemp' tiene que ser siempre una variable cuantitativa, si tiene algún NaN no va a funcionar.

Comment: Y si me encuentro con algun NaN, tendria que transformarlo a cero?

Comment: por que siempre un una data hay valores nulos

Comment: No lo haría... porque cambias el promedio si haces df.fillna(0) en todo caso remueve los casos donde 'ktemp' es NaN

Comment: cuando escribo "perfiles = df.groupby(['alt','date'])

print(perfiles)"

Comment: me imprime <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x000001CFF8D3A308>

Answer (score 2):

Puedes iterar por filas usando `df.iterrows()`, pero el 99% por ciento de las veces la pregunta correcta sería ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto **sin iterar por filas**? Ya que si eliges hacerlo iterando, el bucle de iteración debe ser implementado en python y será lento, mientras que si encuentras otra forma de hacerlo sin escribir bucles (utilizando primitivas de pandas), las iteraciones las realizará pandas internamente, usando implementaciones en C, mucho más rápidas y eficientes.

En este caso lo que quieres es una agrupación de la columna "date", de modo que se junten los valores que sean iguales y se calcule el promedio de la columna "ktemp" para cada uno de esos grupos. Pandas tiene una función para esto:

```
df.groupby(["alt", "date"]).ktemp.mean()
```

Comment: y si encuentro con un NaN en los datos?

Comment: @Pollo okey, escribire una nueva pregunta